# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (with inno db)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

When running:

```
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
  $table->id();
  $table->string('path');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
Schema::create('file_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
  $table->id();
  $table->integer('file_id');
  $table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('files')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->mediumInteger('user_id');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm getting error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `atomes`.`file_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `file_users` add constraint `file_users_file_id_foreign` foreign key (`file_id`) references `files` (`id`) on delete cascade)

None of the internet answers helped me.

I tried changing the table types to `myISAM` but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
        Schema::create('file_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('file_id')->nullable(true)->constrained('files')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Alas, it doesn't work, I still get the error:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `atomes`.`file_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `file_users` add constraint `file_users_file_id_foreign` foreign key (`file_id`) references `files` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

Comment: could you please share the file name of these two table migrations so I could see which table migrates first

Comment: 2023_01_27_211654_user_files.php and 
2023_01_30_192213_files.php

Comment: rename your user_files migrations to `2023_01_30_192214_user_files.php` it because your file_users migration run first before your files migration

Comment: happy to solve your problem